# Why LOCAL_STORAGE doesn't work properly after upgrading from Angular 5 to Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code from the component:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,    
    private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: StorageService) {
      this.countries = this.storage.get("countries");   
      console.log(this.countries);                       
   }
```

I have set the counties in the AppComponent:

```
this.storage.set("countries", data);
```

This code was working fine with no errors on typescript 2.5.3 and Angular 5.
I checked that countries available when loading (console) but I'm not sure
the set I'm doing is correct.

The problem is that the countries are not fetch from the storage.

I believe that something is changed but I'm not sure what. 
Thanks.

Comment: Where is the error hapend ?

Comment: I'll update the question, something else is happening now.